# Count sum of of patterns matches in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a df such as :

```
Groups COL1
G1   Seq:1
G1   Seq:2
G1   Seq_1
G1   Seq:4
G2   Seq_2
G2   Seq_3
G2   Seq_4
G3   Seq:5
G3   Seq:6
G4   Seq:7
G4   Seq_5
```

and I would like to count :

1. Nb Groups with only ":" = 1 (G3)
2. Nb Groups with not only ":" = 2(G1 and G4 )
3. Nb Groups without any  ":" = 1 (G2)

does someone have na idea ? I guess I should sue a `re.sub` and do the sum of each `Groups` in pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to count using [`pd.Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) then use [`GroupBy.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html)

```
om = df['COL1'].str.contains(':')

one = om.groupby(df['Groups']).all().sum() # 1
two = om.groupby(df['Groups']).any().sum() - one # 2 
# minus one because `any` counts all Trues too so we need 
# subtract groups with all Trues.
three = (~om).groupby(df['Groups']).all().sum() # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for mask and then compare by [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) filtered values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with inverted mask by `~` or mask:

```
m = df['COL1'].str.contains(':')

a = np.setdiff1d(df['Groups'], df.loc[~m, 'Groups']).tolist()
print (a)
['G3']

c = np.setdiff1d(df['Groups'], df.loc[m, 'Groups']).tolist()
print (c)
['G2']

b = np.setdiff1d(df.loc[~m, 'Groups'], c).tolist()
print (b)
['G1', 'G4']
```

Anf for count get length of lists:

```
print (len(a))
print (len(b))
print (len(c))
```

Comment: @chippycentra -  So values not important, only counts..